# Upgrade pack from Windows Phone 7.0 to 7.5

Tags: 7.5

I have an "ancient" Windows Phone 7.0, later upgraded to 7.5.  Now I had to return to "Factory Settings" which brought me back to 7.0.  Is it possible to get somewhere the 7.0 to 7.5 5 upgrade pack?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll need the Zune Software for updating WP7 phones - I think you can still [get it here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27163). When you connect your phone it should offer you to download the necessary packages and update your phone - if Microsoft hasn't disabled this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I used this back in the day on my Lumia 710. Dunno if it'll help you.

http://windowsphonehacker.com/articles/want_windows_phone_7.8_now_try_this_easy_tool-01-31-13